# How to get time in specific time zone in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

This question is asked multiple times. But none of the implementations is giving me the right answer.
I'm trying to convert the `UTC` date/time to `IST` (Indian Standard Time) in a select query.

Currently, It's 18:something in IST. in UTC it's 12:something.

The things I tried with their output:

START_TIME(Input): '2021-10-01 12:43:24.014902+00'

`START_TIME AT TIME ZONE 'IST'` → `2021-10-01T10:43:24.014Z`

`(START_TIME AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')::TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'IST'` → `2021-10-01T10:43:24.014Z`

`(START_TIME AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'IST'` → `2021-10-01T09:13:24.014Z`

`(START_TIME::TIMESTAMP) AT TIME ZONE  INTERVAL '+05:30'` → `2021-10-01T07:13:24.014Z`

whereas it should give me `2021-10-01T18:xx:xx.xxxx`

What Am I missing?

UPDATE: `(START_TIME AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') + INTERVAL '05:30 HOURS' AS DATE` gives the desired result. But does adding offset by myself a bad practice?

Comment: I think your IANA name is Asia/Kolkata. ie: select ('2021-10-01 12:43:24.014902'::timestamptz 
at time zone 'utc' at time zone 'Asia/Kolkata')::timestamp;  (IST is for Istanbul AFAIK - +2 as of now)

Comment: @CetinBasoz `2021-10-01T01:43:24.014Z` came as output for your query `(START_TIME::timestamp at time zone 'utc' at time zone 'Asia/Kolkata')::timestamp AS DATE`

Comment: Are you sure? I get 07:13... Check this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=10b84efe1d1ad00db558812b2ec068e3

Comment: @CetinBasoz I'm getting correct output in PgAdmin but wrong in my system. I'm using sequelize in node.js

Comment: I don't know what sequelize does. It might be also doing conversions.

Answer (score 3):

Time zone abbreviations are ambiguous:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_timezone_names WHERE abbrev = 'IST';

        name         │ abbrev │ utc_offset │ is_dst 
═════════════════════╪════════╪════════════╪════════
 Eire                │ IST    │ 01:00:00   │ f
 Asia/Calcutta       │ IST    │ 05:30:00   │ f
 Asia/Kolkata        │ IST    │ 05:30:00   │ f
 Europe/Dublin       │ IST    │ 01:00:00   │ f
 posix/Eire          │ IST    │ 01:00:00   │ f
 posix/Asia/Calcutta │ IST    │ 05:30:00   │ f
 posix/Asia/Kolkata  │ IST    │ 05:30:00   │ f
 posix/Europe/Dublin │ IST    │ 01:00:00   │ f
(8 rows)
```

Be specific and use an unambiguous time zone name:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2021-10-01 12:43:24.014902'
       AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'    /* how late is it when an UTC clock shows the above? */
       AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Kolkata'  /* What does an Indian clock show at that time? */;

          timezone          
════════════════════════════
 2021-10-01 18:13:24.014902
(1 row)
```

Comment: I think there is some issue in my system. Pg-admin gives me correct answer but when I'm running it in `sequelize` in my node environment I'm getting the input itself.

Comment: What data type is your column?

Comment: `timestamp without time zone NOT NULL`

Comment: `Timestamp with out time zone` means the value in stored in the local time zone setting of the server, not UTC (unless `at time zone 'UTC'` was specified on the insert (?)).  Lesson always use `with time zone`.  Also not only are time zone abbreviations are ambiguous, they do not account for Daylight Savings (DST) either. Lesson: always use full timezone  name.

Answer (score 0):

Look, if you have a timestamp without time zone column and you're storing timestamps as UTC, you need to tell PostgreSQL that, and then tell it to convert it to your local time zone. Hope this example will help:

```
select created_at at time zone 'utc' at time zone 'Asia/Kolkata'
from users;
```